# Action-based AllowedHosts instead of entire .net application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

.net (core) allows limiting requests to the application only from certain origins in the appSettings.json file via `AllowedHosts` attribute.

However, for security reasons I want action/controller specific AllowedHosts to an API.

I know that I could create a middleware to check the request's origin and return an Unauthorized status code, but is there an easier way to do this or anyone wants to give an example how this can be done via an action annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`[Host]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.hostattribute) attribute, which is provided for exactly this purpose:

```cs
[Host("example.com", "stackoverflow.com")]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    // …
}
```

You can apply the attribute to controllers and/or actions. An attribute applied to an action *fully* overrides those applied to the containing controller.